# PHP SQLSRV connection “Failed to get DB handle: could not find driver”

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I'm using the following code:

```
try {
    $hostname = "*****";
    $port = 1443;
    $dbname = "*******";
    $username = "********";
    $pw = "************";
    $dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
}
```

Error:

```
Failed to get DB handle: could not find driver
```

The **DLL Files** are already in the **php/ext** and modified in the **php.ini**

What else can I do?

Comment: `dblib` isn't valid. that should be something like `mysql` or whatever - you have to tell PDO what KIND OF database you want it to connect to, not that it's connecting to "a database". it's obviously going to be connecting to a db, and needs to know what language it should speak.

Comment: "DLL Files" is a rather vague description. The `dblib:` prefix assumes *FreeTDS* library [(doc)](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.connection.php), does is show up in phpinfo()?

Comment: Exactly. You either use `new PDO("mysql:...");` for MySQL, `new PDO("pgsql:...");` for PostgreSQL or any other kind supported. Read the PHP Data Objects documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

From the port you're using, it's clear that you're trying to connect to an MSSQL database.

PHP documentation states that the PDO support for connecting to SQLSRV is not recommended for windows machines running php 5.3 or older.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

They do suggest using sqlsrv drivers provided by microsoft.

Link to sqlsrv drivers are in the php link above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mssql_connect?

Here's the syntax: mssql_connect ([ string $servername [, string $username [, string $password [, bool $new_link = false ]]]] )

The implementation would be:

```
$link = mssql_connect($hostname, $username, $pw);
mssql_select_db($dbname, $link);
```

Note that $hostname should contain MSSQL Instance Name. e.g. 'KALLESPC\SQLEXPRESS'